Unable to consume data from kafka topic from kafka in freshly started testcontainer, nondeterministic
I'm facing very weird behavior with kafka testcontainer confluentinc-cp-kafka:6.1.1(it's not related to this, probably), and running out of ideas what can be wrong.
I start my test and kafka testcontainer. I create AdminClient and verify, that all topics I'm interested in are created using adminClient.listTopics(). They are. Then I see warning log made by consumer for that topic:
2024-10-31 11:07:52.111  WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-whateverGroup-2, groupId=whateverGroup] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {whateverTopicName=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

ok, IIUC this just mean, that we have no information about consumer position. Should this be a problem? I don't think so. Now I produce data into this topic. The data will be never consumed.
Now lets keep the testcontainer (kafka server) running and run the test again.
Admin client verifies that the topic exist, warning is not print, because there are data in it, and before I produce anything into that topic, it's immediately read by consumer. The same one, which fails to read them in previous test run. It seems to be some timing issue, when maybe started initializing the consumers before  and it left them in some invalid state or something?
Notes:

there is enough of time to consumed the messages in first run. I patiently wait for several minutes. Even if there is some delay/retry behavior (which there isn't afaik) it would have been reached.
I tried to set auto-offset-reset=earliest to make it super clear, that I don't care about consumer position, but it didn't help either.
I tried to explicitly set auto topic creation, even though it evidently works without any change, both in testcontainer definition and in springboot configuration property.

Can someone explain that?
UPDATE with some 'code':
the test is standard:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {

with @Testcontainers initialized using
@DynamicPropertySource
private static void registerDynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {

It is probably the timing issue. The behavior is nondeterministic. If something happens soon enough, the message 'LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE' won't appear and all my consumers and producers works fine. If something does not happen soon enough, consumers does not work. I can confirm, that I got reported topic existence, after that I got complaing about leader not available and still get defunct consumers. On lucky run, it just works. It seems, that JUnit tests starts too soon; spring app already runs, but if I send some data into kafka topics, it would defunct consumers. If I put Thread.sleep(5000) as first thing in tests, the number of unlucky runs is dramatically lower on my system(I haven't seen unlucky run yet), but it need not to be the correct value for all systems
Any hint about what to look after in logs, or what can I try would be highly welcomed.
I know that there is org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils#waitForAssignment for tests, but this is not applicable for test containers. Is there some variant, where I can test if partitions or assigned?

can you provide the producer and consumer code ?

@Mohamedaminebenhassen Thanks for reply — sadly, I don't have MWE. But I do have guess: if you use EmbeddedKafkaBroker there is method: org.springframework.kafka.test.utils.ContainerTestUtils#waitForAssignment. Use use it to postpone the test execution until kafka is ready. This suggest, that spring test environment is started before kafka is ready. ~ There isn't this method if you use real kafka in testcontainer. If you use good old Thread.sleep at beginning the test with correctly guessed value, it will the the 'same', test will start when kafka is ready and all is "ok".
